# FullCalendar in Ionic3 with Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, fullcalendar

How can I initialize fullCalendar in an event (for example, click) on Ionic 3, and with Angular 4?

This code work when set calendar options in variable:

```
 calendarOptions: Object = {
    fixedWeekCount: true,
    editable: true
  };
```

But when I call into a function, don't work:

```
 buildCalendar(): void{
  this.calendarOptions: Object = {
    fixedWeekCount: true,
    editable: true
  };
 }
```

Html code where the calendar is called

```
<angular2-fullcalendar 
          [options]="calendarOptions" 
          (initialized)="onCalendarInit($event)"></angular2-fullcalendar>
```

Angular code where buildCalendar is called:

```
getAging(): void {

    this.myProvider.getAging()
      .subscribe(
      (response) => {
//do something...
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(`Backend returned code ${error.status}, body was: ${error.error}`);
      }, () => {
        console.log('aging complete');
        this.buildCalendar();
      }
      )

  }
```

PS: *getAging()* is called, on page load.

And I need initialize fullCalender, after load data from backend (API).

Comment: So is it Ionic 2 or Ionic 3? And is the fact that you use it in Ionic really important? It's Angular. What is buildCalendar and where is it called? And how is this.calendarOptions used? Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: @estus sorry, I edit my question. I mentioned Ionic, because I can not tell if it has a different operation than the Angular.

Comment: After installing the plugin to my ionic 3 I am getting a problem with no such file calendar.js. How did you solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue is specific not to FullCalendar in general but to particular `angular2-fullcalendar` component and the way it works.

If it refers to [this one](https://github.com/nekken/ng2-fullcalendar/blob/8a470dc2e423ff42eda81aef1678ffea24895d54/src/calendar/calendar.ts#L31-L36), the problem is clear; it doesn't watch for `options` input and uses `setTimeout` hack to cover initial changes in the input (and 100 ms delay is unwanted here).

Since the component is really simple, it's beneficial for the first party to implement it according to its needs instead of relying third-party solution.

For this particular component `ngIf` should be used. It helps to prevent the component from being compiled until options are ready:

```
<angular2-fullcalendar *ngIf="calendarOptions"
          [options]="calendarOptions" 
          (initialized)="onCalendarInit($event)"></angular2-fullcalendar>
```